# If $T$ is bounded on $S[0,1]$ $\Longrightarrow$ $T$ is bounded on $B[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a  linear operator , $X \;,\;Y$ normed spaces

If $T$ is bounded on $B[0,1]$ , we define $\|T\|:=\sup_{\|x\|\le1} \|T(x)\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1} \|T(x)\|$

If $T$ is bounded on $S[0,1]$ $\Longrightarrow$ $T$ is bounded on $B[0,1]$ ?

$S[0,1]=\{x \in X :||x||=1\}$

$B[0,1]=\{x \in X :||x||\le1\}$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: For $\Vert x\Vert\ne0$, $\Vert Tx\Vert ={\Vert x\Vert}\cdot\Vert T(x/\Vert x\Vert)\Vert$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(\lambda x) = ?$ ... $\lambda =\lambda(\lVert x\rVert)$